How to prevent iptables NAT caused network jitter?
Background is as follows:
Currently, we have an OpenVPN tunnel that connecting from Point A to Point B (Point B has a public IP address), but if the internet route is suboptimal, the latency is quite significant. To improve the latency, we have the idea to utilize a VM on an AWS EC2 instance geographically close to Point B (Point C) to forward(iptables NAT) all TCP packets, by leveraging AWS route, the ping latency reduced, but iptables NAT introduced jitters I believe
Original route as follows:
IP A (OpenVPN client) -> IP B (OpenVPN server) direct connection via internet, ping value: 300 ms
After port forwarding through EC2:
IP A (OpenVPN client) -> IP C (AWS EC2 NAT) -> IP B (OpenVPN server). Using the forwarding via AWS EC2/IP C, the end-to-end latency from IP A to IP B indeed reduces significantly, with lows around 150ms, but occasionally spikes to 250ms likely due to jitter introduced by port forwarding; as the internet network ping values from IP A to IP C, and from IP C to IP B are very stable, consistently around 150 ms in total. Are there any optimization ideas or better implementation methods?
Hopefully there is a optimization measure that does not require touching the configuration of the OpenVPN server.
Thank you in advance.
iptables I used the following two lines:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $AWS_EC2_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination $IP_B:$OPENVPN_PORT

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d $IP_B --dport $OPENVPN_PORT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


What is the path in the other direction? Does B respond directly to A or is there some SNAT to force the return traffic through C?

@u1686_grawity yes, the return traffic also through C.

NAT processing time is constant; there's no reason for it to fluctuate. I suspect your ping spikes are more likely to be bufferbloat. Consider using Cake or FQ-CoDel as your qdisc on all your Linux boxes.
